# Why is category.getUrl() returning incorrect subdomain?

Tags: templating, craft3

Forgive me if this is a server configuration or other issue unrelated to craft, but perhaps someone has some insight on what might be causing this, and how to fix it.

When using a simple `category.getUrl()` for subnav, I am getting odd results where the subdomain is not 'www', but instead something else, like 'ddd' or 'w2w'. This is only happening in the production environment. And results vary depending on which page the nav is included on. Very strange.

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group(group).all() %}
{% for category in categories %}
    <a href="{{ category.getUrl() }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas are much appreciated? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can happen if you use `@web` and let it auto determine your site URL for you.

If you want to use `@web`, try [defining it](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/environments.html#using-aliases-in-control-panel-settings) in your `config/general.php`. This would avoid auto determined URLs from getting stored in your cache.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem was using `@web` for the 'Base URL' setting in 'Settings > Sites'.

I replaced this with an environment variable `BASE_URL="https://www.domain.com"` defined in the .env file, and setting `$BASE_URL` in the 'Base URL' field.

No idea why `@web` doesn't work reliably here, but so be it.

Feel free to delete this question, but I thought I would leave it for others who may encounter the same problem.